# Code won't acknowledge the odd numbers, not placing them in column B

Tags: excel, vba

The task is to write a code that will import the text from a .txt file. In this task, I am to sort the pair and odd numbers in different columns A,B.
The code runs fine by copying over the work of the pair numbers (from the .txt file) but doesn't even copy over the odd numbers.

Tried changing the formula, this is the only one that works.

```
Close #1
Dim xopen As Variant
Dim xclose As Variant

xopen = Application.GetOpenFilename

If xopen = "False" Then
    MsgBox "error nav fails"
Else
    Open xopen For Input As #1
    i = 1
    j = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, st

        If IsNumeric(st) = False Then
            MsgBox "error nav skaitlis(number)"
            Close #1
            Close #2
            Exit Do
        End If

        Line Input #1, st
        If st > 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1) = st
            i = i + 1
        Else
            If Val(st) Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Cells(j, 2).Value = st
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    Close #1
    xclose = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xclose, FileFormat:=xlText
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is inside the `If - Else` logic, try this code and see below for an explanation:

```
If st > 0 Then
    If st Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value2 = st
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Cells(j, 2).Value2 = st
        j = j + 1
    End If
End If
```

The way your code is written you can only enter the `Else` statement when your number `st` is `<= 0`. But you actually want to check  if the number is larger than 0 and if that is true split the numbers into odd and even numbers. Basically your `Else` was in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the reply M.Schalk!

I tried your code, but the outcome is still the same. It doesn't even read the odd numbers in the .txt file. It says "error no number''.

I think the problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your data/ numbers?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DhuocPx

This is what I need to work with. ''test.txt'' is the preferred type of fail. 

The numbers can be any in a range from 1-10000000. The homework we were assigned with, was just constructing a code in excel VBA, that could work and run well. Me as a new student, new to coding, butchered a code together from various posts.

Comment: P.S the numbers can be negative, so idk if,  If st > 0,  Then works

Answer (score 0):

'''
    Line Input #1, st

```
    If IsNumeric(st) = False Then
        MsgBox "error nav skaitlis(number)"
        Close #1
        Close #2
        Exit Do
    End If
```

'''
This was the cause of the problem, deleting this would solve it and let me copy over the odd numbers. It kept looping through that phase. And wouldn't let it go past it.